# ASP.NET Core 2 Partial View List Model binding

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, model

I have a model which has a list of models
`public List<BaseModuleModel> modules { get; set; }`

In my razor file I do a for each loop on all of these modules and then generate the partial view of them and pass in the model.

```
@foreach (BaseModuleModel module in Model.modules)
        {
            <div class="section row col-lg-8">
                <div class="section-header">
                    <p class="header-text">@module.PartialName</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row col-lg-12 section-content">
                    @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Partials/" + module.PartialName + "Partial.cshtml", module)
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

This all works as intended. But when I submit my form the partial view does not change any variables of the `BaseModuleModels`in the list and all of them still have all variables set to null.

How do I make it so even these partial views bind when I click submit my form.

Partial view:

```
@model Lidmaatschap.Models.modules.VoorwaardenModule

<div class="row col-lg-12 section-content">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label asp-for="PrivacyStatement" class="control-label"></label><br />
        <input asp-for="PrivacyStatement" type="checkbox" value="false" /> Ik ga akkoord met de privacy voorwaarden.
        <span asp-validation-for="PrivacyStatement" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control wide-full" />
        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Model class:

```cs
public class VoorwaardenModule : BaseModuleModel
    {
        public VoorwaardenModule() : base("Voorwaarden")
        {

        }

        [Display(Name = "Privacy Verklaring")]
        //[Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "Je moet akkoord gaan met het privacy beleid om door te gaan.")]
        public bool PrivacyStatement { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Voornaam")]
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
```

My Index.cshtml: https://pastebin.com/ErXcJz0a

`MemberModel.cs`: https://pastebin.com/KaSVUV6Q

`HomeController.cs`: https://pastebin.com/YNxJPvmX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partial view needs the parent context to name the form fields properly. By default, it's just going to use the property name of the model that's passed into, so your `PrivacyStatement`-bound input will have `name="PrivacyStatement"`, when what you *actually* need is `name="modules[N].PrivacyStatement"`, in order to properly bind it back on post. As such, you have two issues.

First, you cannot use `foreach`. The partial view is going to need the index of the item in the list, which means you need to actually pass it an indexed item, i.e. `modules[N]`. Second, you need to supply the `HtmlFieldPrefix` from the parent view, while that's possible to do with `Html.PartialAsync`, utilzing the `viewData` param, it's quite arduous and ugly code. It's far better to use the `<partial>` tag helper (which the docs recommend anyways) and its `for` attribute.

Long and short, change you code to:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.modules.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="section row col-lg-8">
        <div class="section-header">
            <p class="header-text">@Model.modules[i].PartialName</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-lg-12 section-content">
            <partial name="~/Views/Partials/@(Model.modules[i].PartialName)Partial.cshtml" for="modules[i]" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've pasted the code in place of what I had previously, but it seems that now when I click submit on my form the object does not seem to make it into the list. My list with Modules is empty. Everything else works fine, it displays as it is supposed to.

Comment: Are you using `BaseModuleModel` as the param type you're binding to on post? That won't work. Based on how model binding works, anything not explicitly on the type being bound to will simply be discarded, so even if you downcast it later in your action to `VoorwaardenModule `, the property will still have no value.

Comment: I am still using the list of `BaseModuleModel`'s yes and in my partial view I have VoorwaardenModule as the model. So it won't work with any type casting.. But right now theres not even an object going into the `List<BaseModuleModel>`

Comment: I'm specifically speaking to the param on your action method. If it's either taking `List<BaseModuleModel>` directly or a type that has a `List<BaseModuleModel>` member, then it will not work, because `PrivacyStatement` does not exists on that class. It must be `List<VoorwaardenModule>`. You can still potentially upcast to `BaseModuleModel` in your views and such, if you need to; it's only truly important for the param(s) being bound to on your action.

Comment: I think I may have explained my question wrong then, my method takes in the `MemberModel` which the `Index.cshtml` uses. Inside the `MemberModel` class I have the `List<BaseModuleModel>` The function the form calls: https://pastebin.com/iftVmuNF

I have added more links to code in the main post

Comment: Yeah. *You can't do that*. The model binder doesn't support polymorphism. It's going to bind the post body to the type that's given, and anything not present on that particular type gets round-filed. In short, after post you literally have `BaseModuleModel` instances, not `VoorwaardenModule` instances, regardless of whether you actually posted `VoorwaardenModule` instances.

Comment: Ah, well thanks for keeping up with me! I'll have to look for another way to do this :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, the whole point of view model is for it to be specific to the view. If you're managing one particular type of module then make your view model use that and have alternate view models of other types. You can use inheritance with the view models to keep most the other props the same. If you need to work with multiple module types in a single view, then your best bet is a super class that encompasses all possible properties, and then you can map to appropriate types based on which properties actually got filled in.