# Partial View Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding

I am building a web application in .Net Core 6.0. I have a main view that is referencing a partial view via the partial view html helper, but the model binding isn't working in that that argument in the controller action result always comes up empty. Snippets of my code are below. I am using third party telerik controls, but I know they are not the issue.

View Code

```
@model ViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("FillList", "Controller", new
            {

            }, FormMethod.Post, null, new { @name = "ListFilterForm", @id = "ListFilterForm" }))
            {
                <partial name="_Filter" model="Model.listTab.FilterViewModel" />
            }

@section Scripts {

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#FilterOfficeDD').change(function() {
                document.ListFilterForm.submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

PartialView Code

```
@using project.Common
@using project.Models;

@model FilterViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Filter";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <fieldset>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Filters.Active, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Filters.Active)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:83%", id = "FilterActiveDD", name="FilterActiveDD" })
            .DataTextField("Text")
            .DataValueField("Value")
            .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
            read.Action(Model.ActiveDDActionResult, Model.Controller).Data("AddUser");
            }).ServerFiltering(false);
            })
            .FillMode(FillMode.None)
            )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Filters.Active, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <input type="hidden" name="activestate" value="@Model.Filters.Active" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3  align-self-center ">
        <input type="submit" Value="View Records" style=" vertical-align:bottom " class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>
```

ViewModel

```
namespace project.Models
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ListTab listTab {get;set;} = new ListTab();
    public class ListTab
        {
            public FilterViewModel PartialFilterViewModel { get; set; } = new FilterViewModel ();
        }
    }
}
```

Partial View ViewModel

```
namespace project.Models
{
    public class FilterViewModel
    {
        public MasterDataModel Filters { get; set; } = new MasterDataModel();

        public string ActiveDDActionResult { get; set; } = "";

        public string Controller { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
```

Controller Code

```
[Route("FillList")]
        public ActionResult FillList(ViewModel model)
        {
        return View("View", ViewModel);
        }
```

The model argument of the FillList action result is the thing that come back empty from the view. I say empty and not null, but all the properties of the class are set to default values.

I have tried just about everything

- Using older model binding techniques from .Net Framework
- Adding a [HttpPost] attribute to the ActionResult
- Moving the BeginForm to outside of the partial view
- Added some different attributes to the action result parameter. things like [FromForm]
- followed this article where you manually set the name of the field as opposed to letting it do it dynamically, but it didn't work. Not sure if it's because it's from an older .net core version

  - [ASP.NET Core 2 Partial View List Model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54866386/asp-net-core-2-partial-view-list-model-binding)
- Was going to try messing with viewbag. Everything that I see says it's totally fine to pass data from the controller to the view using ViewBag, but not the other way around. I also saw that it was removed entirely from .Net Core, so I'm a little confused.

The frustrating part is that if I replace the html helper calling the partial view in the main view with the code from inside that partial view, the binding works without issue.

Comment: You need to use properties, not fields - but your `public ListTab listTab = new ListTab();` member is a field.

Comment: return View("View", ViewModel); is going to return a new or uninitialized "ViewModel".  Your method:  FillList(ViewModel model)  "ViewModel" is type, "model" is name of the object/var passed in.  Also note that you've got 2 view models at play here.  (Why not just use 1?  Make both views use same?:  ex: @model ViewModel for both views (.cshtml files)  I've always used PageModels, myself, much easier to deal with methinks.

Comment: @Dai I edited my post to reflect the fact that the listTab Property is in fact a Property and not a Field. Sorry about that.

Comment: @pcalkins I am unfamiliar with the difference between a PageModel and a ViewModel, but the code in the ActionResult displayed above is only there to as a sort of breakpoint. The issue isn't getting data from the controller to the view, but getting data from the view to the controller.

Comment: nothing from the partial would get there because you're only sending "ViewModel", while the partial is using a different model: @model FilterViewModel  It doesn't know you're binding to the class inside the class (didn't know you could do that actually) in ViewModel.  You've got 2 view models at play here.  The partial is binding to FilterViewModel, but you're only passing in ViewModel.  It'll be much easier if they both share the same model.

Comment: @pcalkins The htmlhelper allows me to define the contents of the (@)model parameter in the partial view <partial name="_Filter" model="Model.listTab.FilterViewModel" />. The data populates just fine when the view renders.

Comment: Yes, that's the way that's working... but your method is taking "ViewModel" as an argument.  The partial is bound to FilterViewModel and so those form fields (inspect in browser to see the names) are named as if there's the one model FilterViewModel.  Not the odd sort of nested "ViewModel.PartialFilterViewModel" where you are making a separate instance of "FilterViewModel".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Shorten Answer

You need use `for` attribute in the partial tag helper:

```
<partial name="_Filter" for="@Model.listTab.PartialFilterViewModel" />
```

---

### Detailed Explanation

> The frustrating part is that if I replace the html helper calling the partial view in the main view with the code from inside that partial view, the binding works without issue.

No matter you use the partial view or directly use the code in the main view, the model binding always cannot work, because you use the `name="FilterActiveDD"` in the html attributes. If you remove this name, directly use the partial view code in main view can work.

Model Binding binds the property by the name attribute, so the name attribute should match the property name. The correct name should be `name="listTab.PartialFilterViewModel.Filters.Active"`.

If you use `model` attribute in the partial tag helper(`<partial name="_Filter" model="@Model.listTab.PartialFilterViewModel" />`
), it would generate the dropdown with `name="Filters.Active"` which does not match the `ViewModel`'s property.

[image]

You need use `for` attribute in the partial tag helper, then it will generate the correct name:

```
<partial name="_Filter" for="@Model.listTab.PartialFilterViewModel" />
```

Client side generated html code:
[image]

Server side receive the value:

[image]

Comment: Ok. So after doing some more testing, it looks like there are a few differences between your answer and what seems to work for me consistently. I was able to get your answer to work the first time without issue, but not more than once.

I ended up having to remove the id and name declarations from the html attributes of the controls in the partial view, then grab the names of the fields from the developer window at runtime and use those as the names that the javascript functions are referencing. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@Rena's answer is correct, but wanted to throw this here to make it easy for future readers.

I had to:

- remove the id and name declarations from the html attributes of the controls in the partial view, then grab the names of the fields from the developer window at runtime and use those as the names that the javascript functions are referencing
- call the partial view using "for=" instead of "model="

New View Code

```
@model ViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("FillList", "Controller", new
            {

            }, FormMethod.Post, null, new { @name = "ListFilterForm", @id = "ListFilterForm" }))
            {
                <partial name="_Filter" for="@Model.listTab.FilterViewModel" />
            }

@section Scripts {

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#listTab_PartialFilterViewModel_Filters_Active').change(function() {
                document.ListFilterForm.submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Notice that I had to preface the reference to the viewModel contents with "for=" by using an "@".

New Partial View Code

```
@using project.Common
@using project.Models;

@model FilterViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Filter";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <fieldset>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Filters.Active, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Filters.Active)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:83%" })
            .DataTextField("Text")
            .DataValueField("Value")
            .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
            read.Action(Model.ActiveDDActionResult, Model.Controller).Data("AddUser");
            }).ServerFiltering(false);
            })
            .FillMode(FillMode.None)
            )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Filters.Active, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <input type="hidden" name="activestate" value="@Model.Filters.Active" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3  align-self-center ">
        <input type="submit" Value="View Records" style=" vertical-align:bottom " class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Something to note is that it seems that the names of the controls use "_" instead of "." when calling subclasses. Not sure if that is unique to Telerik controls, or something else